How to change child process name in android
How to change child process name in android
When I run an app (com.test) and type ps -ef | grep com.test, the output is as follows.
sargo:/ # ps -ef | grep com.test
u0_a111 16103 974 0 01:19:39 ? 00:00:32 com.test
root 21499 21492 15 00:47:45 pts/0 00:00:00 grep com.test

sargo:/ # ps -ef | grep 16103
u0_a111 16103 974 0 01:19:39 ? 00:00:32 com.test
u0_a111 16278 16103 5 01:19:39 ? 01:15:31 cwmwyho


The child process above always changes every time it runs.
And I printed the status information of the child process.
sargo:/ # cat /proc/16278/status

Name: Thread-5
Umask: 0077
State: R (running)
Tgid: 16278
Ngid: 0
Pid: 16278
PPid: 16103
TracerPid: 0
Uid: 10111 10111 10111 10111
Gid: 10111 10111 10111 10111
FDSize: 128
Groups: 3003 9997 20111 50111

...


How can I do this case?
For testing, I implemented the test NDK app as follows.
test.cpp
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LOG_TAG "NDK_TEST"
#define LOGD(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)

#define NAME_LENGTH 6

void generate_random_name(char *name, size_t length) {
    const char charset[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    if (length) {
        --length;  
        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            int key = rand() % (int) (sizeof(charset) - 1);
            name[i] = charset[key];
        }
        name[length] = '\0';
    }
}

void child_process_routine() {
    while (true) {
        LOGD("child process!");
        sleep(5);  
    }
}

void* test_routine(void* arg) {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) { 
        char process_name[NAME_LENGTH + 1];
        generate_random_name(process_name, NAME_LENGTH);

        prctl(PR_SET_NAME, process_name, 0, 0, 0);

        
        child_process_routine();

        exit(0);
    } else if (pid > 0) 
    { 
        LOGD("[*] Started child process with pid %d", pid);
    } else {

        LOGD("Failed to fork\n");
    }
    return NULL;
}

__attribute__((constructor))
static void NDK_test() {
    pthread_t tid;
    LOGD("[*] Starting NDK_test!");

    if (pthread_create(&tid, NULL, test_routine, NULL) != 0) {
        LOGD("Failed to create thread.\n");
    }
}


And I checked with ps -ef
sunfish:/ $ ps -ef | grep com.example.test
u0_a494 15842 1003 11 01:26:19 ? 00:00:00 com.example.test
u0_a494 15886 15842 0 01:26:19 ? 00:00:00 com.example.test

The child process was created, but the child process with the same name as the parent process was created.
In other words, it was not created with a random string.
LOGCAT looks like this:
NDK_TEST com.example.test D child process!
NDK_TEST com.example.test D child process!
NDK_TEST com.example.test D child process!
NDK_TEST com.example.test D child process!
NDK_TEST com.example.test D child process!

How can I create a child process with a random string like below?
My device's OS is Android 12.
u0_a111 16103 974 0 01:19:39 ? 00:00:32 com.test
u0_a111 16278 16103 5 01:19:39 ? 01:15:31 cwmwyho

